# Next/Router emit events

Tags: next.js

I'm writing a custom hook to prevent a user from navigating away if there's unsaved information (in a form) on a page.

To do this, I want to emit a router event when a route change has been cancelled. However, `router.events.emit('routeChangeStart')` causes a a type error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'shallow')`

```html
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useEffect, useCallback } from 'react'

export default function usePreventWindowUnload(preventDefault: boolean) {
  const confirmMessage = 'Are you sure?'
  const router = useRouter()
  
  const onRouterChangeStart = useCallback(() => {
    if (preventDefault) {
      if (window.confirm(confirmMessage)) {
        return true
      }
    }
    // line causing error
    router.events.emit('routeChangeError')
    throw 'cancelled route change'
  ,} [preventDefault])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    router.events.on('routeChangeStart', onRouteChangeStart)
    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeStart', onRouteChangeStart)
    }
  }, [preventDefault])
}
```

How do I fix this?